# Swift unwrapped nil optional does not print in debug panel

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

I had an interesting problem today where a nil optional was unwrapped and the error was not written in the debug panel.

The below examples have a nil value for the var 'datasource'

```
let indexPath = (datasource?.cellAtIndexPath(TableViewRow.Social.indexPath, forEventDetail: self) as! EventDetailSocialTableViewCell).collectionView.indexPathForCell(collectionViewCell)! //[This line highlighted red with the caption EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION]
```

**The debug panel prints: (lldb)**

Here you can see if we split the line up the debug panel prints fine.

```
let tableViewCell = datasource?.cellAtIndexPath(TableViewRow.Social.indexPath, forEventDetail: self)
let indexPath = (tableViewCell as? EventDetailSocialTableViewCell)?.collectionView.indexPathForCell(collectionViewCell)  
let socialOption = socialOptions[indexPath!.row] //[This line highlighted red with the caption EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION]
```

**The debug panel prints: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)**

Has anyone seen this issue (**where the error is not printed**) before in Swift 2.2 ? Worthy of raising as a bug ?

Comment: I think console is empty because Swift is still not very good at long one-line statements. In your first example you are doing a lot of stuff in one line, so it's always better to split such complicated statements.

Comment: Hi @njuri the fact that it's not very good suggests it may be a bug right ? It should 'be good' at it.